# Conditional average in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe, before doing a daily resampling and taking the mean, before eventually taking the rolling mean of 30 days:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.index = ['2009-01-04', '2009-01-05', '2009-01-05', '2009-01-06', '2009-01-06', '2009-01-07', '2009-01-07', '2009-01-07']
df['score1'] = [84, 28, 38, 48, 23, 38, 22, 37]
df['score2'] = [83, 43, 12, 93, 64, 28, 29, 12]
df['score3'] = [92, 33, 11, 48, 23, 22, 12, 38]
df['score4'] = [43, 23, 41, 75, 93, 93, 23, 21]
df['condition1'] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
df['condition2'] = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
df['condition3'] = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]

df = df.resample('D', how='mean')
df = df.rolling(30, min_periods=1).mean()
```

In this case, I'd like to do a 'conditional average' - ie. whenever one of the 3 conditions is ==1, only the 'rows' with a 1, will have their means calculated.
For example, time 3, where condition1 and condition3 are met, we only do average of [38, 12, 11 and 41] for the '2009-01-05', dismissing the [28, 43, 33, 23].

Comment: Although it's subtle - this is almost two/three questions in one... it might be an idea to [edit] this to only just go through calculating the conditional average and then rolling mean, resampling and "weighting" can be follow up questions? Else there's way too much going on here.

Comment: As an aside, why are you building the DataFrame like that? Why not just supply all the data to the actual constructor?

Answer (score 0):

```
# convert your index to datetime:
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# select the rows that meet condition:
df = df[df.loc[:,['condition1','condition2','condition3']].sum(axis=1)>0]

# resample
df = df.resample('D').mean()  # updated syntax

>>> print (df)
            score1  score2  score3  score4  condition1  condition2  condition3
2009-01-04    84.0    83.0    92.0    43.0         0.0         1.0         0.0
2009-01-05    38.0    12.0    11.0    41.0         1.0         1.0         0.0
2009-01-06    35.5    78.5    35.5    84.0         0.5         0.0         1.0
2009-01-07    29.5    20.5    25.0    22.0         0.5         0.5         0.5
```

Comment: thank you but in your example, you're forgetting about the rows that don't have any conditions that are met...

Comment: Your latest request is not clear. In general what you have to do is filter the rows that you want to keep in based on whatever condition that you need. Then resample, consolidate etc. Just take my solution and adjust the second step.